# Calculating time complexity from code line by line for while and switch case and a sample case for insertion sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

There are many guides available which tell you about calculating time complexity from seeing the code/algorithm and applying it line by line. However I am finding it difficult for `while` & `switch` loops. Can someone help me out to clear how to go about in this case?

Sample example of insertion sort and how I am stuck:

```
int i,j,n=a.length,temp; //c1
        for(i=1;i<n;i++) // (n)
        {
            j=i-1; // c2
            temp=a[i]; // c3
            while(j>=0&&a[j]>temp) (Stuck here)
            {
                a[j+1]=a[j];// c4
                j=j-1; //c5
            }
            a[j+1]=temp; //c6
        }
```

Comment: Anyone? Please correct if there is anything wrong in my calculation as well

Comment: Try to find out loop runs for different cases - worst/best/average

Comment: I know that thing. But wanted to calculate just by looking at the code, just like i have tried to present in mt example. For for loop it will be of n order and i am stuck at while loop

Comment: Calculation of complexity is not always that direct. When the number of loop executions depend on actual data(dynamic), you will need to take cases in which the data set is worst/best/average for your algo and decide the complexity accordingly

Comment: Suppose here i take the best case of sorted array in increasing order. For tje for loop it will go with n order. How to go about while loop

Comment: You do not decide best case data set and apply on algo. you decide what is best case for you algo and decide data set. Let me write an answer with best case analysis :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89998/discussion-between-icantcode-and-shiladitya).

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't just going through the collections, but rather, at some point breaking your loops depending on some condition your result will have a *best* case scenario and a *worst* case scenario.

The outer for loop will always perform `n - 1` iterations. When calculating complexities constants are usually omitted, thus your outer loop will have a constant complexity of `n`.

The while loop will depend on two conditions: That `j` is greater than 0 and that `j` is greater than `temp`.

Should `a[j] > temp` hold for every `n`, then your code should have a complexity of `n`.

If on the other hand, `a[j] < temp` for every `n`, then `j>=0` will be the determining condition. `j` will start small and increase as `n` increases, thus both loops would run for `nj` times.

Since `n < nj`, then, you can conclude that the best case scenario has a time complexity of `n`. On the other hand, the worst case scenario is `nj`. Since `j = n - 1`, you could say that the complexity is `n(n - 1)` which would result into `n^2 - n`, which would roughly result in a worst case time complexity of `n^2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider your `while(j>=0&&a[j]>temp)` loop alone then it is an O(1) for the best case cenario and an O(n) for the worst case scenario.

However, if you take both loops into account then the worst case scenario changes a little bit for the inner `while` loop. Here's an example:

- For `i = 1` the inner `while` loop will run 1 time for the worst case scenario.
- For `i = 2` the inner `while` loop will run 2 times for the worst case scenario.
- For `i = 3` the inner `while` loop will run 3 times for the worst case scenario.
- Etc.

Conclusion: the inner `while` loop will execute as many times as the value of `i` for the worst case scenario and just 1 time for the best case scenario.

The total amount of times the inner `while` loop will execute in the worst case scenario will be `1+2+3+...+n` which can be expressed by the following mathematical formula: `n^2/2 + n/2`.

Thus your time complexity for the worst case scenario will be n^2/2 + n/2 which can be simplified to an O(n^2). Your best case scenario will be an O(n).

Comment: Can you explain how it is O(n) and O(1) if i consider the while loop alone for both cases.

Comment: I would then understanf what exactly happens here and then multiply by outer loop of for

Comment: @icantcode The best case scenario for your while loop is when `a[j]`is already bigger than `temp`. Thus the loop will not execute and the time complexity for something that doesn't execute is constant, an O(1).

Comment: @icantcode The worst case scenario for your while loop is when `a[j]` is never bigger than `temp` thus the loop will run for the whole array making it an O(n).